# Neyman "Difference in Means" Estimator and ATE estimator are equivalent?

Tags: statistics

How do I prove that the following two equations are equal? The first equation is an estimator used to find the ATE. The second estimator is the Neyman "Difference in Means" formula. The first estimator shows that under consistency, positivity, and ignorability that it is still *unbiased*

$$1\\τ_{IPW} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_{i}\frac{Di}{p}-Y_{i}\frac{1-D_{i}}{1-p})$$

$$2\\τ =\frac{1}{n_{t}}\sum_{i=1}^nY_{i}D_{i} - \frac{1}{n_{c}}\sum_{i=1}^nY_{i}(1-D_{i})$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Also, what are $p$, $n_c$, and $n_t$?

Comment: p is probability, n is the number of control subjects and n is number of treated subjects. I'm not sure, but I think that in the first equation, it is similar to the idea of the means(control) - mean(treatment) in eq 2 in that for a Bernoulli distribution, 1 is a success and 0 is a failure.

Comment: "p is probability" of what? Is it a given number? Also, you can use "\label{ }" and "\tag{ }" to get numbered equations.

Comment: Ah okay, so I clarified it a little. p is positivity, and in a randomized experiment p = nt/n where nt is the number of trials with treatment and n is the overall number of trials. In this situation we are assuming that there is exactly nt units are treated. So nt/n must equal 1. I see for the first part of equation 1, Yi*(Di/p) would simplify to YiD, but in the second part, it seems to be a divide-by-zero error since 1-(nt/n) = (1-1) = 0 in the denominator.